# Composer not updating to vcs fork

Tags: php, json, github, composer-php

I'm forking a composer third party repo on my github to use instead of the original repo following the instructions on [this page][1]

I committed my changes and also added the **repositories** key to my main application's *composer.json*

however when i run `composer update` I don't see my changes

here is the log

> Reading composer.json of garyrutland/yii2-foursquare-sdk (dev-master)
>   [9.3MB/3.15s] Importing branch dev-master (dev-dev-master)
>   [9.3MB/3.15s] Reading composer.json of garyrutland/yii2-foursquare-sdk
>   (master) [9.3MB/3.15s] Importing branch master (dev-master)
>   [9.4MB/4.10s] Updating dependencies (including require-de   [1]:
>   http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/673/using-your-own-forked-version-of-extensions-with-composer/

here is my main composer.json file

```
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"repositories": {
   "garyrutland/yii2-foursquare-sdk": {
       "type": "vcs",
       "url":  "https://github.com/karneaud/yii2-foursquare-sdk/"
   }
 },
"require": {
    ......
    "garyrutland/yii2-foursquare-sdk":"dev-master@dev",
    .....
},
```

here is my .lock file

```
{
            "name": "garyrutland/yii2-foursquare-sdk",
            "version": "dev-master",
            "source": {
                "type": "git",
                "url": "https://github.com/karneaud/yii2-foursquare-sdk.git",
                "reference": "f48de12dcf608079ac99b245deced7117ec92784"
            },
            "dist": {
                "type": "zip",
                "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/karneaud/yii2-foursquare-sdk/zipball/f48de12dcf608079ac99b245deced7117ec92784",
                "reference": "f48de12dcf608079ac99b245deced7117ec92784",
                "shasum": ""
            },
```

Whatelse I got to do to update the third party repo with my own??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename the branch. `dev-master` still refers to `master`. There is some magic around `dev`, so I'd recommend to avoid it.

```
git checkout dev-master
git branch wip
git push --all -u
```

and change it in `composer.json`:

```
"require": {
    ......
    "garyrutland/yii2-foursquare-sdk":"wip@dev",
    .....
},
```

Or other way round, merge your commits from `dev-master` into `master` and keep working with `master`. It is much simpler.

Comment: yeah dev-master was the problem! Thanks